# Как собрать видео из list[np.array]?

Tags: python, numpy

У меня есть список из np.array. Мне нужно собрать из этого видео и получать на выходе bytes. Вот мой вариант реализации:

```
    def convert_arrays_to_video(array_list: list[np.array]):
        video = io.BytesIO()

        writer = imageio.get_writer(video, format='mp4', fps=30)

        for array in array_list:
            colored_array = np.uint8(cv2.cvtColor(array.plot(), cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
            writer.append_data(imageio.imread(colored_array))

        video_bytes = video.read()

        with open('result.mp4', 'wb') as f:  # временно, для теста
            f.write(video_bytes)

        return video_bytes
```

К сожалению, я получаю ошибку, указываю на imageio.imread(colored_array):

```
OSError: Cannot understand given URI: array([[[ 49,  46,  27],
    [ 59,  59,  40],
   ....
```

Comment: imageio.imread:  Reads an image **from the specified file.**

Comment: @MBo, thanks, but how can i append data with array, then?

Comment: Это их хелпа по imageio.imread. Видимо, вместо чтения из файла нужно использовать готовый массив - colored_array?

Comment: @MBo , я попробовал. Вылетает, что нет разрешения у файла. Подозреваю, что нужно конвертировать все в изображение и предать ему разрешение типа пнг или jpg, а после обратно в array

Comment: @MBo, нет, конвертация не помогает. Та же ошибка -     self.save_args["format"] = format or Image.registered_extensions()[extension]
KeyError: None

Comment: вы не пробовали поменять формат `mp4` на `FFMPEG` внутри `imageio.get_writer`

Comment: @CraSmi, благодарю за совет. На FFMPEG выдает RuntimeError: `FFMPEG` can not handle the given uri.    , однако на AVI, уже выдает файл, но поврежденный. (все array 100% рабочие, каждый во время процесса могу сохранить в jpg/png)

Comment: @CraSmi, похоже, что проблема в io buffer, локально оно сохраняется нормально.

Answer (score 1):

Благодаря комментаторам, удалось решить проблему, поменяв разрешение Writer на avi, а получить байты видео, с помощью video.getvalue(), предварительно выполнив writer.close()